# How to use stackcount bcc tool with Rust?

Tags: rust, memory-leaks, ebpf, bcc-bpf

I would like to create a memory flamegraph of a process using bcc/eBPF as seen [here](https://www.brendangregg.com/FlameGraphs/memoryflamegraphs.html) and using:

```
sudo ./stackcount-bpfcc -p <pid> -U -r ".*malloc.*" -v -d
```

Doesn't seem to write anything interesting in stdout, just have this:

```
cannot attach kprobe, Invalid argument
cannot attach kprobe, Invalid argument
cannot attach kprobe, Invalid argument
cannot attach kprobe, Invalid argument
cannot attach kprobe, Invalid argument
Tracing 86 functions for ".*malloc.*"...
Hit Ctrl-C to end.
```

My executable is written in Rust and was build with `.cargo/config`:

```
[build]
rustflags = "-C force-frame-pointers=yes"
```

Comment: Note that Rust doesn't use `malloc` for memory management. The Rust standard library accesses lower level APIs to get memory from the kernel directly. So the libc uprobes have no reason to be triggered.

Comment: @Jmb thanks, indeed that was the problem, using a simple C program doing simple `malloc`s works.

Comment: @Jmb Could you make your comment into an answer?